# Extract a specific output from a command and save it in a file

Tags: bash

I'm using a command that outputs this :

```
Api key for 'Bouncer':
    6d718520343907968ca8e47d2e4c9046
Please keep this key since you will not be able to retrieve it
```

I want to extract this part `6d718520343907968ca8e47d2e4c9046` and save it in a file key.txt

What is the cleanest way to do this ??

Comment: `command | tail -1`; `command | awk 'END{print $1}'`; `command | grep -v Api`

Comment: Is the output on 2 lines as shown or is it a typo?

Comment: The output is on 3 lines as shown above

Comment: also, if that's a real API token you should invalidate it and create a new one

Comment: Could it be that two blank lines are missing in your output?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==2{print $1}' file.txt
```

or

```
grep 6d file.txt | xargs
```